# How can you explain $\cot(\alpha)= \dfrac{d}{d\theta}\cdot \ln(r) = \dfrac{1}{r} \dfrac{dr}{dt}$ in a polar coordinate system?

Tags: coordinate-systems, derivatives

[This alinea](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poolco%C3%B6rdinaten#Poolvergelijking) is about the $$\cot(\alpha)= \dfrac{d}{d\theta}\cdot \ln(r) = \dfrac{1}{r} \dfrac{dr}{dt}.$$ Where does the $\ln (r)$ come from? How can you derive it from that picture? I want to use that for the $$\nabla f(r,\theta)= \dfrac {\partial f}{\partial r}\vec e_r + \dfrac {1}{r}\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}\vec e_\theta.$$ I know what the definition is of the gradient (i.e. it's a partial derivative of the function with respect to every component in a particular dimension for my case $x,y,z$). The only thing is that I don't know how to convert that to polar coordinates. Can someone please clarify this?

**EDIT**: I know that the derivative of $\ln(x)= 1/x$. So bringing in $\ln r$ would be convenient.

Comment: I'm voting to move this to Mathematics SE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The “physics-y” way to do this is to consider $P$ as the position of a particle moving along the curve $K$. If $\mathbf{r}$ is its position vector from $O$ to $P$, then $\alpha$ is the angle between its velocity vector $\dot{\mathbf{r}}$ (along the tangent line $t$) and the position vector $\mathbf{r}$. So

$$\cos{\alpha}=\frac{\dot{\mathbf{r}}}{|\dot{\mathbf{r}}|}\cdot\frac{\mathbf{r}}{|\mathbf{r}|}$$

In polar coordinates, the position vector is

$$\mathbf{r}=r\hat{\mathbf{r}}.$$

Differentiating it with respect to time gives the velocity vector

$$\dot{\mathbf{r}}=\dot{r}\hat{\mathbf{r}}+r\dot{\hat{\mathbf{r}}}=\dot{r}\hat{\mathbf{r}}+r\dot{\theta}\hat{\mathbf{\theta}}.$$

Thus we have

$$\cos{\alpha}=\frac{\dot{r}\hat{\mathbf{r}}+r\dot{\theta}\hat{\mathbf{\theta}}}{|\dot{r}\hat{\mathbf{r}}+r\dot{\theta}\hat{\mathbf{\theta}}|}\cdot\hat{\mathbf{r}}=\frac{\dot{r}}{\sqrt{\dot{r}^2+r^2\dot{\theta}^2}}$$

which implies

$$\cot{\alpha}=\frac{\dot{r}}{r\dot{\theta}}=\frac{1}{r}\frac{dr}{d\theta}=\frac{d}{d\theta}\ln{r}.$$

Comment: Thx. That refers to a textbook I've found.

Answer (score 1):

I like this solution

```
 How can you derivate it from this picture
```

[image]

Comment: Nice answer, it's simple and useful. But please, you should not post formulae in pictures. Type them instead using Mathjax. There are many reasons, including optimisation of algorithms and helping users whose device doesn't display them well.